# Use cassandra-stress tool to insert specific data, not random

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-stress, cassandra-stress-tool

Is't possible to use cassandra-stress to insert specific data instead of random data ? If yes, how we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, cassandra-stress doesnt support inserting user supplied data. The tool itself will insert the arbitrary data according to your columnspec definition in the input yaml file.